# How to implement an interface in a different OSGi bundle?

Tags: java, osgi, bundles

I have literally just started and I think this is such a basic question that I can't even find anything online about it but I can't for the life of me figure this out.

I have two seperate bundles, one an API and one a Service bundle. In a package in the API bundle I have an interface called "HelloAPI":

```
package com.example.osgi.api;

public interface HelloAPI {

    public void sayHello();

}
```

In the service bundle I have a class with the following code:

```
package com.example.osgi.service;

public class HelloImpl {

    implements HelloAPI {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

but eclipse has highlighted an error under the "implements" keyword which is:

Syntax error on token "implements", interface expected.

I can't see what I've done wrong, can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: `implements` goes right after the class name.  You have a `{` in between.  Also your methods definiton is wrong.  You may want to wait with OSGi until you have your basic understanding of the language in place.  Especially classpaths.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'm being thrown in the deep end here, playing catch-up is all I'm ever doing. What's wrong with my method definition?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html

Comment: Your question is very basic and indicates very little experience with writing Java programs.  If you are expected to do this in an OSGi setting, you are in for a very, very steep learning curve.  If those who threw you in the deep end are unaware of that, this could become a very unpleasant experience.  I would suggest bringing your problems to their attention so you have time to learn the Java basics first.

Comment: You should learn java before OSGi...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly agree with the comments — it's vital to learn the fundamentals of the Java language **before** tackling more advanced topics like modularity.

For reference, here is a correct implementation of your interface:

```java
public class HelloImpl implements HelloAPI {
    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```